# How can i update only some values of a table, which are not one after another or in sequence, with new ones in plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Lets say a have a table of employees:

| ID | PERSON_NAME | PERSON_telephonenumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JOHN | 525323 |
| 2 | NICK | 624534 |
| 3 | GEORGE | 134355 |
| 4 | BILL | 676346 |

How can i update only the person_telephonenumber of nick and bill with new ones that i have been given from an excel file?And are much more than two values.
Please help!

Thank you in advance

Comment: `update employees set PERSON_telephonenumber='newvalue' where PERSON_NAME ='NICK'`?

Comment: ok, but for many values how can this be done? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does many values means many persons? Provide sample of the excel file as well

Comment: Its a very simple excel file with two columns, one column are the values that exist now and the other column the values that have to replace them. very simple. but too many and not one after another in the plsql table.  So in the above lets say you have to replace nick telephone number, after 5 rows bills' number, after ten rows georges' number etc but for hundreds of numbers. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

First step is to make the Excel spreadsheet with two columns into an Oracle table with two columns; let's call them `OLD_NUMBER` and `NEW_NUMBER`. Let's call this table `EXCEL_EXPORT`. Also, you didn't tell us the data type of phone numbers; let's say it's `varchar2(15)`.

**How** to import data from Excel to Oracle is a different question; I assume you do that already, so you know how. (The "how" depends on what you use to interact with the database; for example, I use SQL Developer, and it has very simple tools for this kind of process.)

Then, as an important step, make OLD_NUMBER primary key in the table:

```
alter table excel_export modify (old_number primary key);
```

This allows you to update the existing table through a join:

```
update 
  ( select e.person_telephonenumber, ee.new_number
    from   employees e join excel_export ee
    on     e.person_telephonenumber = ee.old_number )
set person_telephonenumber = new_number
;
```